# Find all matches for given team in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've to a table `matches`. Matches have a `name` and a `uuid` for both teams (`team_a_uuid` and `team_b_uuid`) that play against each other.

```
uuid | name | team_a_uuid | team_b_uuid
-----|------|-------------|------------
d7e..| foo  | 5db46a15-...| 82732895-..
334..| bar  | 75ab1a39-...| 9fcedf80-..
...  | ...  | ...         | ...
```

I've got a second table `teams`.

```
uuid | player_1_uuid | player_2_uuid
-----|---------------|--------------
729..| f432f7bc-63...| e022ccb6-7...
d0f..| c9548a8e-b7...| a28441cb-2...
...  | ...           | ...
```

Here is what I'd like to get: Give me a team and the match uuids it has played in

```
uuid | player_1_uuid | player_2_uuid | match_uuids
-----|---------------|---------------|---------------------
729..| f432f7bc-63...| e022ccb6-7... | {'d7e...', '334...'}
d0f..| c9548a8e-b7...| a28441cb-2... | {'abc...', 'def...'}
```

I'm really stuck here. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `array_agg()`.  You can do this either with an explicit `join` or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(m.uuid)
        from matches m
        where t.uuid in (m.team_a_uuid, m.team_b_uuid)
       ) as match_uuids
from teams t;
```

Comment: Thank you! We are getting there. How would a join look like? And what do you mean with `t2.uuid`?

Comment: Nevermind. If I simply use `select array_agg(uuid)` everything works as expected. Thank you :)

Comment: @zemirco . . . That was a typo.  It has been changed to `m.uuid`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.uuid, t.player_1_uuid, t.player_2_uuid, array_agg(m.uuid) as "match_uuids"
FROM teams t JOIN matches m ON t.uuid IN (m.team_a_uuid, m.team_b_uuid)
GROUP BY t.uuid;
```