# PostgreSQL Find all matches for given player

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is a follow-up question to my last one [Find all matches for given team in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729118/find-all-matches-for-given-team-in-postgresql).

Here is my data structure. I've got `players`

```
uuid | first_name | last_name
-----| -----------| ---------
...  | hard       | hitter
...  | big        | blocker
...  | super      | setter
```

Two players form a team in my `teams` table

```
uuid | player_1_uuid | player_2_uuid
-----|---------------|--------------
729..| f432f7bc-63...| e022ccb6-7...
d0f..| c9548a8e-b7...| a28441cb-2...
...  | ...           | ...
```

And two teams play against each other in a match stored in my `matches` table.

```
uuid | name | team_a_uuid | team_b_uuid
-----|------|-------------|------------
d7e..| foo  | 5db46a15-...| 82732895-..
334..| bar  | 75ab1a39-...| 9fcedf80-..
...  | ...  | ...         | ...
```

In my previous question I asked about getting a team and all the match uuids it has played in. Here is one solution

```
select t.*,
    (select array_agg(m.uuid)
    from matches m
    where t.uuid in (m.team_a_uuid, m.team_b_uuid)
    ) as match_uuids
from teams t;
```

Now I'd like to go one step further: Give me a player and the match uuids it has played in. It's a bit more complicated because we have to get the teams first and then the matches. I'd like to get something like this

```
uuid | first_name | last_name | team_uuids    | match_uuids
-----| -----------| ----------|---------------|---------------
...  | hard       | hitter    | {'...', '...'}| {'...', '...'}
...  | big        | blocker   | {'...', '...'}| {'...', '...'}
...  | super      | setter    | {'...', '...'}| {'...', '...'}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't actually run the query (no real tables to test) but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT
    players.uuid,
    players.first_name,
    players.last_name,
    array_agg(teams.uuid) AS team_uuids,
    array_agg(matches.uuid) AS match_uuids
FROM
    players
    JOIN teams
    ON (players.uuid = teams.player_1_uuid OR players.uuid = teams.player_2_uuid)
    JOIN matches
    ON (teams.uuid = matches.team_a_uuid OR teams.uuid = matches.team_b_uuid)
GROUP BY
    players.uuid,
    players.first_name,
    players.last_name;
```

I suppose, that in the `GROUP BY` clause the `players.uuid` column is enough if it is the primary key - you can try to remove the `players.first_name` and `players.last_name` columns.

Comment: It works :) Thank you! I'm getting duplicate UUIDs in `team_uuids`. Is `array_agg(distinct teams.uuid) AS team_uuids` the right way to remove duplicates?

Comment: @zemirco, yes `array_agg(distinct teams.uuid)` will remove duplicates (and sort uuids by the way). I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @zemirco . . . I'm looking forward to your next question where you ask how to have this return in a finite amount of time.

Comment: I'm quite new to SQL. Is the performance of those queries that bad? Or what do you mean with your comment? How could I improve them?